# SQL Server Remote Access - Can't Connect

Tags: sql, sql-server, port, remote-access

I've tried enabling TCP/IP - setting tcp port - restarting sql service - creating firewall inbound rule for the port - allowing  remote connections on sql server - I'm able to ping - server name: tcp:, with correct credentials - server name: , and still not working.

What am I missing?

Error I'm getting:

```
Cannot connect to <server name>
```

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP
>   Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.) (Microsoft SQL
>   Server, Error: 258)

Comment: Can you connect locally? What does `telnet <server> 1433` return?

Comment: I can connect locally just not remotely.

Comment: And what does telnet from the remote client return?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are not setting the domain users then make sure you are using SQL Server authentication and either set up local user in the database or simply use the `sa` user (not recommended)
2. Because you are not specifying the SQL Server edition, please take a look this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/914277/how-to-configure-sql-server-2005-to-allow-remote-connections) for enabling remote access if you are using SQL Server 2005

Comment: This was my suspicion that I wasn't specifying something in the server name when trying to connect. Ill play with that